# Using "test" DB in GUI integration tests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, selenium, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a Spring MVC + JPA/Hibernate application. The application has some GUI (Selenium) tests. I use `tomcat7-maven-plugin` to deploy my application for these tests:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This setup works fine with the production DB, but I need to use another DB for these tests. My DB connection settings are defined in a Spring config and `.properties` files.

How can I change the DB connection settings when I deploy the application for GUI tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create two Spring profiles in the Spring config: one for production (containing DB connection settings for the production DB), and another for integration tests (containing DB connection settings for the test DB).

2) Add the following configuration to `tomcat7-maven-plugin`:

```
<configuration>
    <systemProperties>
        <!--Replace `nameOfYourSpringTestProfile` with the name of your actual test profile. -->
        <spring.profiles.active>nameOfYourSpringTestProfile</spring.profiles.active>
    </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```

This configuration will set the `spring.profiles.active` system variable in the deployed application, which will activate the test profile and the corresponding DB connection settings.